# ActiveRecord Query returns array of IDs but I want links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a query

```
pack.pages.where("thumbnail is null or printable_page is null or preview is null or vuforia_archive is null or unity_bundle is null")
```

which returns, as an example a list of Page IDS, `[34,54,15]`

but what I would like is a link to each of their edit pages (*this code would be `edit_admin_page_path(page)` for one page*)

[[34](http://www.google.com),[54](http://www.gooogle.com),[15]](http://www.google.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get list of comma-separated page links like this, if that's what you want:

```
pack.pages.where("thumbnail is null or printable_page is null or preview is null or vuforia_archive is null or unity_bundle is null").map{|page| edit_admin_page_path(page)}.join(',')
```

Or if you want HTML:

```
pack.pages.where("thumbnail is null or printable_page is null or preview is null or vuforia_archive is null or unity_bundle is null").map{|page| "<a href='#{edit_admin_page_path(page)}'}>#{page.id}</a>"}.join()
```